# LaTeX won't compile because of use of _ in text

Tags: symbols, compiling

LaTeX won't let me use _ in my text, it keeps trying to compile it as math and therefore won't compile my pdf.

Anyone knows how I can make it not do that?

I'm using it in the following:

```
\textit{item_name}
\textit{current_item.name}
\textit{_qty}
\textit{id='small_qty'}
```

Comment: Use 'small\\_qty' instead

Comment: @GHL I tried that and it still wont let me compile.

Comment: Seems like i forgot one! Thank you. It worked now!

Comment: That's great! Glad it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_
```

is a special character in Latex, you need to use

```
\_
```

instead

Comment: Worked perfectly!