# How to display non-formatted mathematical like expression?

Tags: math-mode, errors, symbols, verbatim

What I want to do is to display

kl_div(y,x)-log(2)*y -2*x + 30 <= 0, x > 0, y > 0}

in its original format, however LaTex maybe think that is a formula, and continuously warn me that

```
Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.498 kl_
         div(y,x)-log(2)*y -2*x + 30 <= 0, x > 0, y > 0
```

However I don't think I have any unclosed $ sign or something, and when I add $ sign to the formula, everything goes well.

I also made it with `\text {div(y,x)-log(2)*y -2*x + 30 <= 0, x > 0, y > 0}`, same warning occurs.

Comment: You probably want `\verb` or a `verbatim` environment.

Comment: As Andrew suggested use `\verb@kl_div(y,x)-log(2)*y -2*x + 30 <= 0, x > 0, y > 0@`.  You don't have to use `@` as a delimiter, you can choose any symbol that is not contained in the text between them.

Comment: See also [LaTeX won't compile because of use of _ in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186924/latex-wont-compile-because-of-use-of-in-text).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks you! Could you write your answer instead of just commenting?